# How does Meteor's reactivity work behind the scenes?

Tags: meteor

I have read the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/) and looked at the [source behind reactivity](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/tracker/tracker.js),  but I don't understand it.

Can someone explain how this works behind the scenes, as it looks like magic to me :).

Answer (score 99, accepted):

So it's actually rather straight forward, at a basic level there are 2 types of functions involved:

1. Functions that create a reactive context (reactive function)
2. Functions that invalidate a reactive context (invalidating function)
3. Functions that can do both. (I lied there are 3)

When you call a `reactive function` it creates a `context` that meteor stores globally and to which the `reactive function` subscribes an `invalidation` callback. The function that you pass to a reactive function, or any functions that run from within it, can be an `invalidating function` and can grab the current `context` and store it locally. These functions can then at any time, like on a db update or simply a timer call, invalidate that `context`. The original `reactive function` would then receive that event and re-evaluate itself.

Here's a step by step using meteor functions (note that `Tracker.autorun` used to be called `Deps.autorun`):

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){ 
  alert("Hello " + Session.get("name"));
});

Session.set("name", "Greg");
```

1. autorun takes a function as its parameter
2. before autorun runs this function, it creates a `context`
3. autorun attaches a callback to the `context`'s invalidation event
4. This callback will re-run the function passed to autorun
5. The function is then run in the `context` for the first time.
6. Meteor stores this `context` globally as the currently active `context`
7. Inside the function is another function: Session.get()
8. Session.get() is both a `reactive function` and an `invalidating function`
9. Session.get sets up it's own `context` and associates it internally with the key "name"
10. Session.get retrieves the current context (autorun's context) globally from meteor
11. The invalidation callback that Session.get registers to it's own context, will simply invalidate it's enclosing context (in this case, autorun's context)
12. So now we have 2 contexts, autorun's and session.get's
13. when these functions return, meteor cleans up the active context global variable
14. Session.set is another function capable of invalidating a `context`.
15. in this case we're invalidating all `context`s created by Session associated with the key "name"
16. All of those `contexts`, when invalidated, run their invalidation callbacks.
17. Those callbacks just invalidate their enclosing `context`s (That's the design of Session.get and not what a invalidation callback must do)
18. Those enclosing `contexts` now run their invalidation callbacks.
19. In the autorun case, that callback runs the function we originally passed to autorun and then sets up the `context` again.

**The whole implementation is actually rather straight forward as well, you can see it here:**
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/tracker/tracker.js

**And a good example of how it works can be found here:**
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/reactive-dict/reactive-dict.js

**Reactive programming is not actually meteor or JS specific**
you can read about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming

Comment: Great explanation this should be in the meteor page.

Comment: This video was very helpful http://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-reactivity-with-contexts

Comment: The apostrophe in "autosubscribe takes a function as **it's** parameter" really shouldn't be there!

Comment: The link to the implementation is now invalid

Comment: @skagedal deps is now called tracker, see: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/tracker/tracker.js

Comment: @ephemer Thanks, I've updated the answer, waiting for peer review.