# How to make a session variable reactive?

Tags: meteor

I'm running Meteor 0.5.7, and trying to display a bootstrap alert message when user clicks submit.

**client.js**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('isSuccessful',function(input){
  return Session.get("success");
});    

Template.form.events({
  'click .submit' : function (event, template) {
     if (condition) {
        Session.set("success", true);
        // hide warning, show success
        $('#valid_form').show();
        $('#invalid_form').hide();
     } else {
        Session.set("success", false);
        // hide success, show warning
        $('#valid_form').hide();
        $('#invalid_form').show();
     }
  } 
});

Template.form.rendered = function () { $('.alert').hide();};
```

**page.html**

```
<body>
   {{> page}}
</body>

<template name='page'>
  {{> form}}
</template>

<template name='form'>
   <!-- Show Alerts Above Form -->
   <div class="alert alert-success" id="valid_form">..</div>
   <div class="alert" id="invalid_form">..</div>

   {{#if isSuccessful}}
     <div>SHOW CONFIRMATION PAGE</div>
   {{else}}
    <div>SHOW INPUT FIELDS</div>
   {{/if}}
   <div>   
</template>
```

When the user INITIALLY clicks submit and the condition is not met, they have to click submit again in order to get the warning message. All other times the logic works.

I've looked at this - [How does Meteor's reactivity work behind the scenes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260015/how-does-meteors-reactivity-work-behind-the-scenes), and re-read the Meteor docs on reactive programming parts, but something is still amiss.

Shouldn't the else statement in the client default to a session variable of success == false, and the handlebar template pick it up immediately in the {{else}} block? SLightly confused. Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

The answer to my question appears to be that changing return Session.get("success") to return Session.equals("success",true) in the handlebar registered helper did the trick. From what I'm reading, it has less "invalidations"? - not sure what that's suppose to mean atm, but it's a start!

Answer (score 2):

If your purpose is to hide/show the relevant alerts on a condition, you can just do this instead:

**client.js**

```
Template.form.rendered = function() {
  // hide all alerts when elements are rendered
  $('.alert').alert('hide');
}

Template.form.events({
  'click .submit' : function (event, template) {
    if (condition) {
      // hide warning, show success
      $('#valid_form').alert();
      $('#invalid_form').alert('hide');
    } else {
      // hide success, show warning
      $('#valid_form').alert('hide');
      $('#invalid_form').alert();
    } 
  } 
});
```

**page.html**:

```
<body>
  {{> page}}
</body>

<template name='page'>
  {{> form}}
</template>

<template name='form'>
  <div class="alert alert-success" id="valid_form">..</div>
  <div class="alert" id="invalid_form">..</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Your suggestion would have one of the alerts alway show, when I only want it to show when needed. To clarify, the alerts should only popup when the form fields are valid or not, and the form fields are not shown in the example just to keep it short. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: `$('.alert').alert('hide')` hides all alerts when template is rendered

Comment: Prashant, thanks for your diligence, I updated the template to reflect what I am working with locally. As you can see, I'd like the alerts to  show outside the other html elements that may or may not have alert status.