# Reactive object bindings in a non-shiny context

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

### Actual question

How could you either approximate the [reactive environment/behavior](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson6/) established by [shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com) functions or possibly even use these very functions in a **non-shiny** context in order to create "reactive" variables?

### Background

I'm absolutely fascinated by the [shiny framework](http://shiny.rstudio.com) and its underlying paradigms. In particular with respect to the established overall reactive environment. Just for the pure fun of it, I wondered if one could transfer this reactive programming paradigm to a non-shiny context - i.e. a regular R application/project/package or however you want to call it.

Maybe think *options*: you might want `option_2` to depend on the value of `option_1` to ensure 
consistent data states. If `option_1` changes, `option_2` should change as well.

I guess I'm idealy looking for something as efficient as possible, i.e. `option_2` should **only be updated when necessary**, i.e. when `option_1` actually changes (as opposed to computing the current state of `option_2` **each time** I query the option).

### Due dilligence

I played around a bit with the following functions:

- `shiny::reactiveValues`
- `shiny::reactive`
- `shiny::observe`
- `shiny::isolate`

But AFAIU, they are closely tailord to the shiny context, of course.

### Own prototype

This is a very simple solution based on `environment`s. It works, but

1. I'd be interested in different/better approaches and
2. I thought maybe one could actually reuse shiny code somehow.

**Definition of `set` function**:

```
setValue <- function(
  id,
  value,
  envir,
  observe = NULL,
  binding = NULL,
  ...
) {

  ## Auxiliary environments //
  if (!exists(".bindings", envir, inherits = FALSE)) {
    assign(".bindings", new.env(), envir)
  }    
  if (!exists(".hash", envir, inherits = FALSE)) {
    assign(".hash", new.env(), envir)
  }
  if (!exists(".observe", envir, inherits = FALSE)) {
    assign(".observe", new.env(), envir)
  }
  if (!exists(id, envir$.hash, inherits = FALSE)) {
    assign(id, new.env(), envir$.hash)  
  }

  ## Decide what type of variable we have //
  if (!is.null(observe) && !is.null(binding)) {
    has_binding <- TRUE
  } else {
    has_binding <- FALSE
  }

  ## Set //
  if (has_binding) {
  ## Value with binding //
    ## Get and transfer hash value of observed variable:
    assign(id, get(observe, envir$.hash[[observe]]), envir$.hash[[observe]])
    ## Compute actual value based on the binding contract/function:
    out <- binding(x = get(observe, envir))
    ## Store actual value:
    assign(id, out, envir)
    ## Store hash value:
    assign(id, digest::digest(out), envir$.hash[[id]])
    ## Store binding:
    assign(id, binding, envir$.bindings)    
    ## Store name of observed variable:
    assign(id, observe, envir$.observe)    
  } else {
  ## Regular variable without binding //
    ## Store actual value:
    out <- assign(id, value, envir)
    ## Store hash value:
    assign(id, digest::digest(value), envir$.hash[[id]])
  }

  return(out)

}
```

**Definition of `get` function**:

```
getValue <- function(
  id,
  envir,
  ...
) {

  ## Check if variable observes another variable //
  observe <- envir$.observe[[id]]

  ## Get //
  if (!is.null(observe)) {
  ## Check if any of observed variables have changed //
  ## Note: currently only tested with bindings that only 
  ## take one observed variable 
    idx <- sapply(observe, function(ii) {
      hash_0 <- get(ii, envir$.hash[[ii]], inherits = FALSE)
      hash_1 <- get(id, envir$.hash[[ii]], inherits = FALSE)
      hash_0 != hash_1
    })

    ## Update required //
    if (any(idx)) {
      out <- setValue(
        id = id, 
        envir = envir, 
        binding = get(id, envir$.bindings, inherits = FALSE),
        observe = observe
      )
    } else {
      out <- get(id, envir, inherits = FALSE)
    }
  } else {
    out <- get(id, envir, inherits = FALSE)
  }

  return(out)

}
```

**Apply:**

```
##------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## Apply //
##------------------------------------------------------------------------------

require("digest")
envir <- new.env()  

## Set regular variable value //
setValue(id = "x_1", value = Sys.time(), envir = envir)
[1] "2014-09-17 23:15:38 CEST"
getValue(id = "x_1", envir = envir)
# [1] "2014-09-17 23:15:38 CEST"

## Set variable with binding to observed variable 'x_1' //
setValue(
  id = "x_2", 
  envir = envir,
  binding = function(x) {
    x + 60*60*24
  }, 
  observe = "x_1"
)
# [1] "2014-09-18 23:15:38 CEST"

## As long as observed variable does not change, 
## value of 'x_2' will also not change
getValue(id = "x_2", envir = envir)
# [1] "2014-09-18 23:15:38 CEST"

## Change value of observed variable 'x_1' //
setValue(id = "x_1", value = Sys.time(), envir = envir)
# [1] "2014-09-17 23:16:52 CEST"
## Value of 'x_2' will change according to binding contract/function:
getValue(id = "x_2", envir = envir)
# [1] "2014-09-18 23:16:52 CEST"
```

**Profiling:**

```
##------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## Profiling //
##------------------------------------------------------------------------------

require(microbenchmark)

envir <- new.env()  
binding <- function(x) {
  x + 60*60*24
}

microbenchmark(
  "1" = setValue(id = "x_1", value = Sys.time(), envir = envir),
  "2" = getValue(id = "x_1", envir = envir),
  "3" = setValue(id = "x_2", envir = envir,
    binding = binding, observe = "x_1"),
  "4" = getValue(id = "x_2", envir = envir),
  "5" = setValue(id = "x_1", value = Sys.time(), envir = envir),
  "6" = getValue(id = "x_2", envir = envir)
)

# Unit: microseconds
#  expr     min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#     1 108.620 111.8275 115.4620 130.2155 1294.881   100
#     2   4.704   6.4150   6.8425   7.2710   17.106   100
#     3 178.324 183.6705 188.5880 247.1735  385.300   100
#     4  43.620  49.3925  54.0965  92.7975  448.591   100
#     5 109.047 112.0415 114.1800 159.2945  223.654   100
#     6  43.620  47.6815  50.8895 100.9225  445.169   100
```

Comment: This pretty much already exists if you use a language for a graphical interface (e.g., tcl/tk). Take a look at, for example, the [playwith](https://github.com/floybix/playwith/tree/master/R) plotting GUI. Outside of a GUI approach, `makeActiveBinding` is probably something worth examining.

Comment: I'm not sure if it can be used to truly mimic the reactive functionality, but I sometimes use (abuse?) `eval` with expressions, calls, and quotes to avoid extra copying operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a collection of `test_that` unit tests in location `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/shiny/tests/`. They give you a good idea of how the functions/wrappers:

- `reactiveValues`
- `reactive`
- `observe`
- `isolate`

can be used outside of a `shinyServer` call.

The key is to use `flushReact` to make the reactivity fire off. Here, for example, is one of the tests in file `test-reactivity.r`, and I think it already gives you a good sense of what you need to do:

```
test_that("overreactivity2", {
  # ----------------------------------------------
  # Test 1
  # B depends on A, and observer depends on A and B. The observer uses A and
  # B, in that order.

  # This is to store the value from observe()
  observed_value1 <- NA
  observed_value2 <- NA

  values <- reactiveValues(A=1)
  funcB  <- reactive({
    values$A + 5 
  })  
  obsC <- observe({
    observed_value1 <<-  funcB() * values$A
  })  
  obsD <- observe({
    observed_value2 <<-  funcB() * values$A
  })  

  flushReact()
  expect_equal(observed_value1, 6)   # Should be 1 * (1 + 5) = 6
  expect_equal(observed_value2, 6)   # Should be 1 * (1 + 5) = 6
  expect_equal(execCount(funcB), 1)
  expect_equal(execCount(obsC), 1)
  expect_equal(execCount(obsD), 1)

  values$A <- 2
  flushReact()
  expect_equal(observed_value1, 14)  # Should be 2 * (2 + 5) = 14
  expect_equal(observed_value2, 14)  # Should be 2 * (2 + 5) = 14
  expect_equal(execCount(funcB), 2)
  expect_equal(execCount(obsC), 2)
  expect_equal(execCount(obsD), 2)
})
```

Answer (score 6):

For those interested: this kept bugging me over the weekend, so I've put together a little package called [reactr](https://github.com/Rappster/reactr) that is based on the way bindings can be defined via `makeActiveBinding`. You can find the basic idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25922934/implementing-reactive-variables-data-binding-with-makeactivebinding).

### Main features

- Supported monitoring scenarios: the package allows the definition of *simple monitoring* scenarios as well as more complex ones such as *arbitrary functional relationships*, *mutual bindings* and different environments for "source" and "target" variables (see arguments `where` and `where_watch`).
- Caching: this way of creating bindings uses cached values wherever possible for reasons of efficiency (if monitored variable has not changed, it's okay to use the cached value instead of re-running the binding function each time).
- As a reference, I still kept the solution based on the concept in my question above. It's available via `binding_type = 2`. However, it doesn't support the use of the syntactical sugars for `assign()` and `get()` (`<-` and `<obj-name>` or `$<obj-name>`) for keeping the hash values in sync - so I wouldn't use it I guess.

### Drawback

What I don't really like about it is that I need an auxiliary environment for storing the hash values that are compared in order to make the decision "update cache or return cache". It floats around in `where`, currently in `where$._HASH` by default (see [`ensureHashRegistryState()`](https://github.com/Rappster/reactr/blob/master/R/ensureHashRegistryState.r), but at least you can change the name/ID to one you like better or need (see argument `.hash_id`).

**If someone has any idea on how to get rid of that, it'd be very grateful! :-)**

---

### Example

See [`README.md`](http://github.com/Rappster/reactr/blob/master/README.md)

Load:

```
require("devtools")
devtools::install_github("Rappster/classr")
devtools::install_github("Rappster/reactr")
require("reactr")
```

Use an example environment so we don't mess up our `.GlobalEnv`:

```
where <- new.env()
```

#### Binding scenario 1: simple monitoring (identical values)

Set a variable that can be monitored:

```
setReactive(id = "x_1", value = 10, where = where)
```

Set a variable that monitors `x_1` and has a reactive binding to it:

```
setReactiveid = "x_2", watch = "x_1", where = where)
```

Whenever `x_1` changes, `x_2` changes accordingly:

```
where$x_1 
# [1] 10
where$x_2
# [1] 10
where$x_1 <- 100 
where$x_2
# [1] 100
```

Note that trying to change `x_2` is disregarded as it can only monitor `x_1`:

```
where$x_2 <- 1000
where$x_2
# [1] 100
```

#### Binding scenario 2: simple monitoring (arbitrary functional relationship)

```
setReactiveid = "x_3", watch = "x_1", where = where, binding = function(x) {x * 2})
```

Whenever `x_1` changes, `x_3` changes accordingly:

```
where$x_1 
# [1] 100
where$x_2
# [1] 100
where$x_3
# [1] 200
where$x_1 <- 500
where$x_2
# [1] 500
where$x_3
# [1] 1000
```

#### Binding scenario 3: mutual binding (identical value)

Set two variables that have a mutual binding.
The main difference to *Binding scenario 1* is, that you can set 
both `x_1` **and** `x_4` and have the changes reflected.

In order to do that, it is necessary to reset the binding for `x_1` as well 
with `mutual = TRUE`:

```
setReactive(id = "x_1", watch = "x_4", where = where, mutual = TRUE)
setReactive(id = "x_4", watch = "x_1", where = where, mutual = TRUE)
```

Whenever `x_1` changes, `x_4` changes accordingly and vice versa.

Note that variables with mutual bindings are merely initialized by `setThis` and have a default value of `NULL`. You must actually assign a value to either one 
of them via `<-` **after** establishing the binding:

```
where$x_1
# NULL
where$x_4
# NULL

where$x_1 <- 100
where$x_1
# [1] 100
where$x_4
# [1] 100
where$x_2
# [1] 100
where$x_3
# [1] 200

where$x_4 <- 1000
where$x_4
# [1] 1000
where$x_1
# [1] 1000
where$x_2
# [1] 1000
where$x_3
# [1] 2000
```

#### Binding scenario 4: mutual binding (valid bi-directional relationship)

```
setReactive(id = "x_5", watch = "x_6", where = where, 
  binding = function(x) {x * 2}, mutual = TRUE)
setReactive(id = "x_6", watch = "x_5", where = where, 
  binding = function(x) {x / 2}, mutual = TRUE)

where$x_5 <- 100
where$x_5
# [1] 100
where$x_6
# [1] 50

where$x_6 <- 500
where$x_6
# [1] 500
where$x_5
# [1] 1000
```

### Further examples

See `?setReactive` and `?setReactive_bare`.

---

### Profiling

I've included a profiling script in [`/inst/prof/prof_1.r`](https://github.com/Rappster/reactr/blob/master/inst/prof/prof_1.r). There is a "bare" S3 method `setThis_bare` that is roughly 10 % faster.

Using S4 method `setValue()`

```
where <- new.env()  

res_1 <- microbenchmark(
  "1" = setReactive(id = "x_1", value = 10, where = where),
  "2" = getReactive(id = "x_1", where = where),
  "3" = setReactive(id = "x_2", where = where, watch = "x_1",
    binding = function(x) {x + 100}),
  "4" = getReactive(id = "x_2", where = where),
  "5" = setReactive(id = "x_1", value = 100, where = where),
  "6" = getReactive(id = "x_2", where = where),
  control = list(order = "inorder")
)

Unit: microseconds
 expr     min       lq   median       uq      max neval
    1 476.387 487.9330 494.7750 545.6640 7759.026   100
    2  25.658  26.9420  27.5835  30.5770   55.166   100
    3 644.875 657.7045 668.1820 743.6595 7343.364   100
    4  34.211  35.4950  36.3495  38.4870   86.384   100
    5 482.802 494.7750 505.4665 543.9535 2665.027   100
    6  51.744  53.0280  54.3100  58.1595   99.640   100
```

Using S3 function `setThis_bare()`

```
where <- new.env()

res_3 <- microbenchmark(
  "1" = setReactive_bare(id = "x_1", value = 10, where = where),
  "2" = getReactive(id = "x_1", where = where),
  "3" = setReactive_bare(id = "x_2", where = where, watch = "x_1",
    binding = function(x) {x + 100}),
  "4" = getReactive(id = "x_2", where = where),
  "5" = setReactive_bare(id = "x_1", value = 100, where = where),
  "6" = getReactive(id = "x_2", where = where),
  control = list(order = "inorder")
)

Unit: microseconds
 expr     min       lq  median       uq      max neval
    1 428.492 441.9625 453.936 567.4735 6013.844   100
    2  25.659  26.9420  27.797  33.9980   84.672   100
    3 599.546 613.0165 622.852 703.0340 2369.103   100
    4  34.211  35.9220  36.777  45.5445   71.844   100
    5 436.189 448.1630 457.571 518.5095 2309.662   100
    6  51.745  53.4550  54.952  60.5115 1131.952   100
```

---

### For the ones interested in the nitty gritty details

This is how the boilerplate code looks like that is fed to `makeActiveBinding()` inside of `setThis()` (leaving out the `message()` stuff; see [`/R/getBoilerplateCode.r`](https://github.com/Rappster/reactr/blob/master/R/getBoilerplateCode.r)).

**Variable that can be monitored:**

```
out <- substitute(
  local({
    VALUE <- NULL
    function(v) {
      if (!missing(v)) {
        VALUE <<- v
        ## Ensure hash value //
        assign(id, digest::digest(VALUE), where[[HASH]][[id]])
      }
      VALUE
    }
  }),
  list(
    VALUE = as.name("value"),
    HASH = as.name(".hash_id")
  )
)
```

Ready for evaluation:

```
getBoilerplateCode(
  ns = classr::createInstance(cl = "Reactr.BindingContractMonitored.S3")
)
```

**Variable that monitors:**

```
out <- substitute(
  local({
    if (  exists(watch, envir = where_watch, inherits = FALSE) &&
          !is.null(get(watch, envir = where_watch, inherits = FALSE))
    ) {
      VALUE <- BINDING_CONTRACT
    } else {
      VALUE <- NULL
    }
    function(v) { 
      if (exists(watch, envir = where_watch, inherits = FALSE)) {  
        if (missing(v)) {
          hash_0 <- where_watch[[HASH]][[watch]][[watch]]
          hash_1 <- where_watch[[HASH]][[watch]][[id]]
          if (hash_0 != hash_1) {
            VALUE <<- BINDING_CONTRACT
            where_watch[[HASH]][[watch]][[id]] <- hash_0
            where[[HASH]][[id]][[id]] <- hash_0
            where[[HASH]][[id]][[watch]] <- hash_0
          } 
        }
      }
      VALUE
    }
  }),
  list(
    VALUE = as.name("value"), 
    BINDING_CONTRACT = substitute(.binding(x = where_watch[[watch]])),
    HASH = as.name(".hash_id")
  )
)
```

Ready for evaluation:

```
getBoilerplateCode(
  ns = classr::createInstance(cl = "Reactr.BindingContractMonitoring.S3")
)
```

**Variable with mutual bindings:**

```
out <- substitute(
  local({
    if (  exists(watch, envir = where, inherits = FALSE) &&
          !is.null(get(watch, envir = where, inherits = FALSE))
    ) {
      VALUE <- BINDING_CONTRACT
    } else {
      VALUE <- NULL
    }
    function(v) {
      if (!missing(v)) {
        VALUE <<- v
        ## Update hash value //
        assign(id, digest::digest(VALUE), where[[HASH]][[id]])
      }
      if (exists(watch, envir = where, inherits = FALSE)) {
        if (missing(v)) {
          hash_0 <- where[[HASH]][[watch]][[watch]]
          hash_1 <- where[[HASH]][[watch]][[id]]
          if (hash_0 != hash_1) {
            VALUE <<- BINDING_CONTRACT
            where[[HASH]][[watch]][[id]] <- hash_0
            where[[HASH]][[id]][[id]] <- hash_0
            where[[HASH]][[id]][[watch]] <- hash_0
          }
        }
      }
      VALUE
    }
  }),
  list(
    VALUE = as.name("value"), 
    BINDING_CONTRACT = substitute(.binding(x = where[[watch]])),
    HASH = as.name(".hash_id")
  )
)
```

Ready for evaluation:

```
getBoilerplateCode(
  ns = classr::createInstance(cl = "Reactr.BindingContractMutual.S3")
)
```

Answer (score 3):

(Tried to leave this as a comment but S.O. said it was too long.)

Kudos for looking more closely at reactivity. You may find these two links helpful:

- https://jcheng.shinyapps.io/reactivity-dsc2014
- [How does Meteor's reactivity work behind the scenes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260015/how-does-meteors-reactivity-work-behind-the-scenes) (Shiny's reactive core was largely inspired by Meteor)

So actually Shiny's reactivity can be used outside of Shiny applications--with two tricks.

1. If you attempt to read a reactive expression or reactive value from the console, you'll get an error. I intentionally did this because in a fundamentally reactive system like Shiny it's almost always a bug to read a reactive value or expression from a non-reactive context (hopefully that sentence makes sense if you've read the two links above). However when you're driving at the console it's pretty reasonable to want to circumvent this check. So you can set `options(shiny.suppressMissingContextError=TRUE)` to make it go away.
2. When you do stuff that triggers reactivity, observers aren't actually executed until you call `shiny:::flushReact()`. This is so that you can perform multiple updates and then let all the reactive code respond once, instead of recalculating with every update. For console use, you can ask Shiny to automatically call `flushReact` on every console prompt by using `shiny:::setAutoflush(TRUE)`. Again, this is only needed for observers to work.

An example that works today (execute this line by line at the console):

```
library(shiny)
options(shiny.suppressMissingContextError=TRUE)

makeReactiveBinding("x_1")
x_1 <- Sys.time()
x_2 <- reactive(x_1 + 60*60*24)
x_1
x_2()
x_1 <- Sys.time()
x_1
x_2()

# Now let's try an observer
shiny:::setAutoflush(TRUE)
observe(print(paste("The time changed:", x_1)))
x_1 <- Sys.time()
```

I would recommend taking another look at leveraging Shiny's reactive abstractions more directly. I think you can achieve a syntax like this quite straightforwardly with `makeActiveBinding` (assuming you think this is better than what Shiny gives you today):

```
where <- new.reactr()
where$x_1 <- Sys.time()
where$x_2 <- reactive(x_1 + 60*60*24)
where$x_1  # Read x_1
where$x_2  # Read x_2
```

One key advantage to declaring reactive expressions using `reactive()` rather than `setThis` is that the former can easily and naturally model expressions that depend on multiple reactive values/expressions at once. Note that reactive expressions are both cached and lazy: if you modify `x_1` it will not actually recalculate `x_2` until you try to read `x_2`, and if you read `x_2` again without `x_1` having changed then it'll just return the previous value without recalculating.

For a more functional twist on Shiny reactivity, see Hadley Wickham's new package https://github.com/hadley/shinySignals that is inspired by [Elm](http://elm-lang.org/).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot, I'll definitely take a look at it!

Comment: Tried to combine the two approaches :-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Rappster, Joe and Robert, your conversations have really benefited me a lot.

I have just writen a small tool to build a cacheable function using the following idea:

```
library(shiny)
gen.f <- function () {
    reactv <- reactiveValues()

    a <- reactive({ print('getting a()'); reactv$x + 1 })
    b <- reactive({ print('getting b()'); reactv$y + 1 })
    c <- reactive({ print('getting c()'); a() + b() })

    function (x.value, y.value) {
        reactv$x <<- x.value
        reactv$y <<- y.value
        isolate(c())
    }
}
f <- gen.f()
```

In the above example, the parent environment of the returned function
was used to store the reactive values and the reactive expressions.

By doing so, the returned function will have the ability to cache its
intermediate results and do not need to recalculate them if the function
is further called with the same arguments. The underlying reactive expressions are wrapped inside and the function can be
used as normal R functions.

```
> f(6,9)
[1] "getting c()"
[1] "getting a()"
[1] "getting b()"
[1] 17
> f(6,9)
[1] 17
> f(6,7)
[1] "getting c()"
[1] "getting b()"
[1] 15
```

Based on this idea, I wrote a tool to help generate this kind of cacheable
function with the following syntax. You can see my repo at https://github.com/marlin-na/reactFunc

```
myfunc <- reactFunc(
    # ARGV is the formal arguments of the returned function
    ARGV = alist(x = , y = ),

    # These are reactive expressions in the function argument form
    a = { print('getting a()'); x + 1 },
    b = { print('getting b()'); y + 1 },
    ans = { print('getting ans()'); a() + b() }
)
> myfunc(6, 9)
[1] "getting ans()"
[1] "getting a()"
[1] "getting b()"
[1] 17
> myfunc(6, 9)
[1] 17
> myfunc(6, 7)
[1] "getting ans()"
[1] "getting b()"
[1] 15
```

Regards,

M;

Comment: Great to hear that! Here's to social coding, keep on hacking away :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Joe's pointers I was able to **significantly** simplify the design. I'd really like **not** needing to worry about if some variable is a reactive variable or not (the former implying that you'd have to execute the underlying reactive binding function via `()` as in `x_2()` in Joe's answer above). So that's why I tried combining Joe's code with `makeActiveBinding()`.

### Pros

- there's no need for the hash environment `where$._HASH` anymore and the actual reactivity details are left up to `shiny` - which is awesome because if someone knows how to master reactivity done in R it's probably the RStudio guys ;-) Also, that way the whole thing might be even compatible with `shiny` apps - well, at least theoretically ;-)
- as Joe pointed out, `reactive()` doesn't care how many observed variables you feed to it - as long as they are in the same environment (arg `env` in `reactive()`, arg `where` in my code).

### Cons

- I think you loose the ability to definie "mutual dependency" this way - at least AFAICT so far. The roles are pretty clear now: there's a variable that can be overserved and might be set explicitly, and the other one really **just** observes.
- The return value of `reactive()` is quite tricky as it suggests a much simpler object than is actually returned (which is a Reference Class). This makes it hard to combine with `substitute()` "as is" as this would result in a somewhat static binding (works for the very first cycle, but then it's static).

  I needed to use the good old workaround of going all the way back to transforming the whole thing to a `character` string:

  ```
  reactive_expr <- gsub(") $", ", env = where)", capture.output(reactive(x_1 + 60*60*24))
  ```

  Probably a bit dangerous or unreliable, but it seems that the end of `capture.output(reactive())` always has that trailing whitespace which is goot for us as it let's us identify the last `)`.

  Also, this comes with kind of a *Pro* as well: as `where` is added *inside* `setReactive`, the user does not need to specify `where` twice - as would otherwise be needed:

  ```
  where <- new.env()
  setReactive("x_1", reactive(x_2 + 60*60*24, env = where), where = where)
  ```

### So, here's the draft

```
require("shiny")

setReactive <- function(
  id = id,
  value = NULL,
  where = .GlobalEnv,
  .tracelevel = 0,
  ...
) {
  ## Ensure shiny let's me do this //
  shiny_opt <- getOption("shiny.suppressMissingContextError")
  if (is.null(shiny_opt) || !shiny_opt) {
    options(shiny.suppressMissingContextError = TRUE)  
  }

  ## Check if regular value assignment or reactive function //
  if (!inherits(value, "reactive")) {
    is_reactive <- FALSE
    shiny::makeReactiveBinding(symbol = id, env = where)
    value_expr <- substitute(VALUE, list(VALUE = value))
  } else {
    is_reactive <- TRUE
    ## Put together the "line of lines" //
    value_expr <- substitute(value <<- VALUE(), list(VALUE = value))
    ## --> works initially but seems to be static
    ## --> seems like the call to 'local()' needs to contain the *actual*
    ## "literate" version of 'reactive(...)'. Evaluationg it  
    ## results in the reactive object "behind" 'reactive(()' to be assigned
    ## and that seems to make it static.

    ## Workaround based character strings and re-parsing //
    reactive_expr <- gsub(") $", ", env = where)", capture.output(value))
    value_expr <- substitute(value <<- eval(VALUE)(), 
                             list(VALUE = parse(text = reactive_expr)))
  }

  ## Call to 'makeActiveBinding' //
  expr <- substitute(
    makeActiveBinding(
      id,
      local({
        value <- VALUE
        function(v) {
          if (!missing(v)) {
              value <<- v
          } else {
              VALUE_EXPR
          }
          value
        }
      }),
      env = where
    ),
    list(
      VALUE = value,
      VALUE_EXPR = value_expr
     )
  )
  if (.tracelevel == 1) {
    print(expr)
  }
  eval(expr)

  ## Return value //
  if (is_reactive) {
    out <- get(id, envir = where, inherits = FALSE)
  } else {
    out <- value
  }
  return(out)
}
```

### Testing in .GlobalEnv

```
## In .GlobalEnv //
## Make sure 'x_1' and 'x_2' are removed:
suppressWarnings(rm(x_1))
suppressWarnings(rm(x_2))
setReactive("x_1", value = Sys.time())
x_1
# [1] "2014-09-24 18:35:49 CEST"
x_1 <- Sys.time()
x_1
# [1] "2014-09-24 18:35:51 CEST"

setReactive("x_2", value = reactive(x_1 + 60*60*24))
x_2
# [1] "2014-09-25 18:35:51 CEST"
x_1 <- Sys.time()
x_1
# [1] "2014-09-24 18:36:47 CEST"
x_2
# [1] "2014-09-25 18:36:47 CEST"

setReactive("x_3", value = reactive({
  message(x_1)
  message(x_2)
  out <- x_2 + 60*60*24
  message(paste0("Difference: ", out - x_1))
  out
}))
x_3
# 2014-09-24 18:36:47
# 2014-09-25 18:36:47
# Difference: 2
# [1] "2014-09-26 18:36:47 CEST"
x_1 <- Sys.time()
x_1
# [1] "2014-09-24 18:38:50 CEST"
x_2
# [1] "2014-09-25 18:38:50 CEST"
x_3
# 2014-09-24 18:38:50
# 2014-09-25 18:38:50
# Difference: 2
# [1] "2014-09-26 18:38:50 CEST"

## Setting an observer has no effect
x_2 <- 100
x_2
# [1] "2014-09-25 18:38:50 CEST"
```

### Testing in custom environment

Works analogous to using `.GlobalEnv` except that you need to state/use `where`:

```
where <- new.env()
suppressWarnings(rm(x_1, envir = where))
suppressWarnings(rm(x_2, envir = where))

setReactive("x_1", value = Sys.time(), where = where)
where$x_1
# [1] "2014-09-24 18:43:18 CEST"

setReactive("x_2", value = reactive(x_1 + 60*60*24, env = where), where = where)
where$x_2
# [1] "2014-09-25 18:43:18 CEST"
where$x_1 <- Sys.time()
where$x_1
# [1] "2014-09-25 18:43:52 CEST"
where$x_2 
# [1] "2014-09-25 18:43:52 CEST"
```

### A couple of follow up questions (mostly directed to Joe if you're still "listening")

1. If not taking care of chipping `env` in via string manipulation as I do it, how would I be able to access/alter the environment of the actual function/closure that defines the reactivity (to prevent the need to state the environment twice)?

   ```
   func <- attributes(reactive(x_1 + 60*60*24))$observable$.func
   func
   # function () 
   # x_1 + 60 * 60 * 24
   # attr(,"_rs_shinyDebugPtr")
   # <pointer: 0x0000000008930380>
   # attr(,"_rs_shinyDebugId")
   # [1] 858
   # attr(,"_rs_shinyDebugLabel")
   # [1] "Reactive"
   ```

   **EDIT:** 
   Figured that out: `environment(func)`
2. Is there any way to realize "mutual dependencies" as the one realized with my code above with existing shiny functionality?
3. Just a "far-off" thought without a specific use case behind it: would it be possible to have the observed variables live in *different* environments as well and still have `reactive()` recognize them appropriately?

Thanks again, Joe!