# Retrieving reactive dependencies as inferred by shiny::reactive()

Tags: r, reverse-engineering, shiny, reactive-programming

Consider this [presentation](https://jcheng.shinyapps.io/reactivity-dsc2014/#13) of Joe Cheng were he explains how he and his colleagues implemented the reactive framework in shiny (which is inspired by [Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260015/how-does-meteors-reactivity-work-behind-the-scenes)):

[image]

### Actual question

Could someone explain to me how I would go about finding out about a **reactive object's dependencies** (i.e. listing their names and environments, actually accessing them, etc.) that have been automatically inferred by `shiny::reactive()`?

More specifically, I'd like to use that information in my custom "one-stop-shop" function [`setShinyReactive`](https://github.com/Rappster/reactr/blob/master/R/setShinyReactive.r) (package [`reactr`](https://github.com/Rappster/reactr)) that builds on top of shiny functionality.

It must be somehow possible via methods of one of these components/classes:

1. a *reactive conductor* (I'm guessing mainly class `shiny::Observable`)
2. a *reactive endpoints/observers* (I'm guessing mainly class `shiny::Observer`)
3. a *reactive context* (I'm guessing mainly classes `shiny::Context` and `shiny::ReactiveEnvironment`)

But I'm still kind of lost regarding the actual details on this.

### Due dilligence

You can find my forked version of shiny that I used for my reverse engineering efforts [here](https://github.com/Rappster/shiny-forked). [This `.Rnw` file](https://github.com/Rappster/shiny-forked/blob/rappster/inst/jt/reverse_engineering.Rmd) represents my current status of knowledge and questions about the actual implementation.

### Short example of `shiny::reactive()`

```
require(shiny)
## Ensure that shiny let's us do our thing //
shiny_opt <- getOption("shiny.suppressMissingContextError")
if (is.null(shiny_opt) || !shiny_opt) {
  options(shiny.suppressMissingContextError = TRUE)  
}

a <- 10
shiny::makeReactiveBinding("a")
b <- shiny::reactive(a * 2)
## --> this leads to the inferred result that `b` depends on `a`; 
## this information is stored somewhere in the shiny framework 
## --> that's what I want to get at
b()

a <- 20
b()
```

### Background: bi-directional bindings

The reason I'd like to be able to do that is that I'd like to be able to specify **bi-directional reactive bindings** via original (or only slightly adapted) shiny functionality (for examples see this [README](https://github.com/Rappster/reactr#scenario-4-bi-directional-1)).

Joe, who has been really helpful and dedicated so far - but who is also short on time, got me started with this:

```
require(shiny)
## Ensure that shiny let's us do our thing //
shiny_opt <- getOption("shiny.suppressMissingContextError")
if (is.null(shiny_opt) || !shiny_opt) {
  options(shiny.suppressMissingContextError = TRUE)  
}

suppressWarnings(rm(a, b))
options(shiny.suppressMissingContextError=TRUE)
makeReactiveBinding("a")
makeReactiveBinding("b")
observe(a <<- b)
observe(b <<- a)
shiny:::setAutoflush(TRUE)
(a <- 1)
b
(b <- 2)
a
(a <- 3)
b
```

However, in order to integrate that into my implementation of [`setShinyReactive`](https://github.com/Rappster/reactr/blob/master/R/setShinyReactive.r), I need to figure out if the statement `o$.value <<- v` (**currently line 203**) is valid or not:

```
## Call to 'makeActiveBinding' //
makeActiveBinding(
  id,
  env = where,
  fun = local({
    visible
    o
    function(v) {
      if (missing(v)) {

      } else {
        if (strict_set == 0) {
          o$.value <<- v    
          ## --> this should only be allowed for bi-directional relationships
        } else if (strict_set == 1) {

          [...]

        } else if (strict_set == 2) {

          [...]

        }
      }
      [...]
    }
  })
)
```

This is only the case for **bi-directional** reactive objects as they are sort of "hybrids": both *reactive conductors* **and** *reactive sources* at the same time.

**That's why I need to figure out if a *bi-directional situations* exists or not - which in turn implies that I need to find out each objects dependencies**

For my other, sort of "pedestrian", take on reactivity based on [`setReactive`](https://github.com/Rappster/reactr/blob/master/R/setReactive.r), I queried bi-directional dependencies via method [`.hasBidirectional`](https://github.com/Rappster/reactr/blob/master/R/ReactiveObject.S3.r#L408). That's the information that I'd like to retrieve from the correct shiny instance/class that actually holds this information somewhere.