# Connecting values of sliderInput in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I've been stuck with this simple problem:

Shiny app uses several sliderInputs that are placed in different tabs in standard fluidPage. When one slider is moved, other sliders should move accordingly.

I've been working with updateSliderInput() function placed in observe()

Are there any other functions or procedures that can change values of selected sliders? I've also been experiencing that when I swich to other tab, the initial value of slider is set as in the beggining even though it should have been changed by updateSliderInput().

I'd be really thankful if someone could reference me to some function or algorithm that could help me.

Bonus points: I also need to do this for selectInput and radioButtons

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem and followed an example from
[R shiny bi-directional reactive widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827962/r-shiny-bi-directional-reactive-widgets)
It works for me. Please see the following:

#### R code

```
ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel(""),
fluidRow(
    column(3,
           wellPanel(
             
               uiOutput('slider1'),
               uiOutput('text1')
           ))
    
))


server <- function(input, output) {

output$slider1<-renderUI({
    text1.value<-input$slider1
    default.slider1<-if(is.null(text1.value)) 15 else text1.value
    textInput("text1", label="slider",
              value = default.slider1)
})

output$text1<-renderUI({
    slider1.value<-input$text1
    default.text1<-if(is.null(slider1.value)) 15 else slider1.value
    sliderInput("slider1", label = h5("text"),
                min = -10, max = 10, value = default.text1,step = 1)
})}
```

Just realized this question is posted a long time ago. Still hope it helps!

Comment: Links break. Then your answer turns completely useless. Please summarize the essentials of that solution and add that to your answer!

Comment: Hi, I do not know the reason why the link did not work for you.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)

Comment: I am not saying that the link is broken *now*. But it can break tomorrow. Do you volunteer to come back to your answer each day this site exists; in order to check if the link is still working?

Comment: I see. Thank you both! This is actually my first time answering a question. Will try to follow your suggestions and summarize the answer!

Comment: BTW, I have posted a question related to R shiny as well. This is urgent and I am really anxious. Could you please help? Thanks again.