# In a given reactive, is there a method/option to get the reactive element(s) that triggered it?

Tags: r, shiny

For example, I could simply add a print statement at the beginning of my reactive of interest to find out each time what other reactive triggered it?

```
    reactive_example <— reactive({
    print(last_trigger())
    reactive_statement()
    _#Rest of reactive logic..._
    )}
```

Then for example, I would see in my log:

> "last_trigger of reactive_example: reactive_statement"

Which would mean that on this particular occasion, it's reactive_statement() that triggered reactive_example() to re-run.

Comment: Have a look at this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26915964/retrieving-reactive-dependencies-as-inferred-by-shinyreactive

Comment: @PorkChop I don't see how this could be a duplicate :) Your linked post like your answer only touches on inputs, while my question is really after other reactive statements...so alas it's not a duplicate. But thx for the help.

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1846

Comment: @gregL It's exactly that!  :) So I assume, since this is a recent request, that 1) it's not in yet, 2) my usage is valid, 3) that github discussion is the best place to upvote...Thank you!!

Comment: That link by Greg is what you need

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

**To monitor all reactives:**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(column(3,
                   sliderInput("one","one",min = 0,max = 5,step = 1,value = 1),
                   sliderInput("two","two",min = 0,max = 5,step = 1,value = 1),
                   verbatimTextOutput("x"))
  )
)

server <- function(input,output,session){

  v <- reactiveValues(last = NULL)

  observe({
    lapply(names(input), function(x) {
      observe({
        input[[x]]
        v$last <- x
      })
    })
  })

  output$x <- renderPrint({paste0("Last Value changed is: ", v$last)})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

**To monitor the reactives you are interested in:**
Below we only want to see the changes in sliders "one" and "two" that may be a part of some reactive like `reactive_example()`

```
 observe({
    lapply(c("one","two"), function(x) {
      observe({
        input[[x]]
        v$last <- x
      })
    })
  })
```

Comment: Thank you. useful trick. But inputs are 'easy' when you debug, what i'm looking for is which other **reactives** triggered the reactive of interest. I've updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, I've written a package that does this by parsing the reactive log: https://github.com/glin/reactlog

There's a summary of a couple other ideas I tried on the GitHub issue.

https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1846#issuecomment-361831280